# Get contents with JS and echo with PHP

Tags: php

I'm not familiar with js. I'd like to get the result of "file_get_contents" function and put it on the "source" (I have marked both with .................).

Thank you in advance.

```
<script>
var myInit = {
referrer: '',
};
function file_get_contents(filename) {
fetch(filename, myInit).then((resp) => resp.text()).then(function(data) {
    content = JSON.parse(data)
    fetch(content['some']['media']['content'], myInit).then((resp) => 
resp.text()).then(function(data));});}
file_get_contents("https://.................");
</script>

<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clappr@latest/dist/clappr.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<div id="player"></div>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var player = new Clappr.Player({
            source: '<?php echo $url...................?>',
            parentId: "#player",
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
            autoPlay: true,
        });};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all file_get_contents() is PHP default function so i m not sure if you sould use same name for custom functions. .

Comment: You should achive this using javascript. You can't use javascript in PHP.

Comment: I need to use file get contents from JS function, since it it works different

Comment: You should either implemented all in javascript, i.e. do the `file_get_contents` function in javascript, and instead of `function(data)` put your `player = new Clappr.Player` code, or you should do both parts in php, i.e. use phps `file_get_contents` and echo the `$url` where you get the url from `file_get_contents`

Comment: @Ingus `file_get_contents()` is a php function and OP is naming his javascript function `file_get_contents`

Comment: @B001ᛦ wow did not noticed that :O Sorry ;)

Comment: @Adder I replaced 'function(data)' to 'player = new Clappr.Player... etc.' but what should I put in 'source:'?

Comment: You should put the **argument** of `file_get_contents()` (not its result) in `source` - the player will get the file itself.

Comment: I thought you'd want to put `data` into it or a field `data.url` or so. Do `console.dir(data)` to see what is in there on the js console.

Comment: @IVOGELOV what do you mean? I tried with source: 'file_get_contents()', but it does not work.

Comment: @SalvaRF Have you tried with `source: "https://................."` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you use the following code, you will get closer to your solution.

```
<script>
var myInit = {
referrer: '',
};
function file_get_contents(filename) {
fetch(filename, myInit).then((resp) => resp.text()).then(function(data) {
    var content = JSON.parse(data);
    console.dir(content);
    var player = new Clappr.Player({
            source: content['some']['media']['content'],
            parentId: "#player",
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
            autoPlay: true,
        });
    });
}
file_get_contents("https://.................");
</script>

<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/clappr@latest/dist/clappr.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<div id="player"></div>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        //Whatever
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you tell me what console.dir outputs, I might be able to offer more help.

BTW.: doesn't clapper have some documents showing how to use its API?